# how can create carousel for posts that will be published a month later?

Tags: events

I have WordPress theme, which is consist of many published post (some of them expired and some of them not published so far). Each of These posts scheduled by start (published on) and expiration (Post Expirator plugin) event. I use two carousel post slider in my home page. One for “Fairs are being held” and one for “Fairs are one month left to be held”. My problem is that how can create carousel for posts that will be published a month later??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question could have more info as it's unclear exactly what you're trying to do.

With the info provided, the simple answer to your question "how can I create a carousel for posts that will be published a month later" is to use tags and categories, depending on which carousel plugin you're using. For example, one carousel could display the "Current" category while the other carousel displays the "Later" category.

The Post Expirator plugin is not related to your carousel; it only adds and removes posts. If you wanted to automate the process and this option is not offered by the plugin, you'll have to use php to modify the plugin.

Comment: My problem is that categories aren’t time dependent feature. My website consist of many different event posts. These posts import from a CSV file at the beginning of the year, how can show my posts on a carousel slider a month before an event held?? I hope this question is clear and understandable enough. Thanks a lot

Comment: You should edit your question to include the new details as it will get lost in the comments. So essentially you want to have 2 carousels with different post, each post will have a different expiry date and needs to be imported by csv. When a post is removed from one carousel it's automatically added to the other. If you can't find a plugin that already does this you'll have to write it in php or modify an existing plugin. You should at least try something and post your code for help.